# How to resolve NotImplementedError for client.auth.approle.login of hvac

Tags: python, hashicorp

Objective of program : To fetch hashicorp vault data and establish connection

Tech : Python 3.7.3, Hvac library

Error : Program fails when trying to authenticate using client.auth.approle.login of hvac

Sudo code :

```
import hvac
client = hvac.Client(url='myurl',namespace='xyz',verify=false)

client.auth.approle.login(role_id='',secret_id='')

print(client.is_authenticated())

read_response = client.secrets.kv.v2.read_secret_version(path='somepath')
```

Answer (score 0):

`AppRole` has been implemented on [`hvac`](https://pypi.org/project/hvac/) starting from version [`0.10.6`](https://github.com/hvac/hvac/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md#0106-december-14th-2020). Try to install the latest version instead. At the time of this writing it's `0.11.2`